# different questions with similar answers

Tags: discussion, answers, best-practice

I noticed that there are situations when **different questions**, with **different contexts**, have very **similar answers**.

**Question:** Is it OK if I post a "generic" question and I also provide the answer to it?

The idea is that in the future a link would be sufficient as an answer.

With this kind of "strategy", we may be able to create a "best practices" repository - even with dedicated tags and so on. Or make them "sticky".

Comment: There is a badge, answer your own question and get 3 or more votes. I assume this makes it okay. Although here on TWP it's not promoted that we post hypothetical questions

Comment: :) I forgot about this badge. I was more concerned about the generic nature of the question. I am not speaking about hypothetical questions, I am talking about an umbrella question / answer for many concrete questions.

Comment: We're still going to get the situation specific ones either way

Comment: So you say we should not even try? My idea would be to try once-twice, see how it turns out, and then make a decision.

Comment: I'm not saying don't try, I'm saying it won't solve most the umbrella question issues. But it's still a reasonable idea in order to help people with a general question

Comment: my bad, I understood wrong initially. tnx.

Answer (score 3):

We sometimes do have canonical questions posted by experienced users in order to get a general guidance for very commonly asked questions. My recommendation is to post on Meta what specific generic question you would like to ask and why, and see what the community thinks on your specific proposal. Many common topics already have a large number of good questions and answers, so it may not be useful to create a new question just for the sake of being generic.

Answer (score 0):

The majority of questions here can be answered by just two answers, one proactive and the other reactive.

**Proactive:**

> Ask your manager

**Reactive**

> Use headphones

(note that this answer contains traces of humour, please ask staff if you suffer from any allergies)

Comment: It's worth noting that that the efficacy of the former declines if performed simultaneously with the latter.